# Normal bundle of reducible nodal curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

Let $X=\mathbb P^3_k$ ($k=\bar k$) and $l_1,l_2,l_3$ three distinct lines such that $l_1\cap l_2\neq \emptyset$,$l_2\cap l_3\neq \emptyset$, $l_1\cap l_3=\emptyset$ and $l_2\cap l_3\neq l_1\cap l_2$ (a chain). Is there a nice presentation (for example in using the normal bundle of the lines) of the normal bundle $\mathcal N_{\Gamma/X}$ of the locally complete intersection curve $\Gamma=l_1\cup l_2\cup l_3$.

Comment: Up to projective linear transformations, there is only one such chain.  So if you work out the answer in one case, you will have worked it out in every case.  One approach: use the fact that such a chain is a Cartier divisor of type $(2,1)$ in a smooth quadric surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Comment: Using my previous comment, the normal bundle $N$ appears to be $E\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{\Gamma}}\mathcal{O}(2,2)|_{\Gamma}$, where $E$ is the unique nontrivial extension of $\mathcal{O}_{\Gamma}$ by $\omega_{\Gamma}$, cf. my preprint with de Jong ["Divisor classes and the virtual canonical bundle for genus 0 maps"](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~jstarr/papers/cc.pdf).  In particular, there is a short exact sequence, $$0 \to \mathcal{O}(2,1)|_{\Gamma} \to N \to \mathcal{O}(2,2)|_{\Gamma} \to 0.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It should be an other question but are there similar methods to compute the normal bundle of a Néron polygon in $\mathbb P^n_k$ (whose ideal is generated by quadrics) ?

Comment: "... are there similar methods to compute the normal bundle ..."  Perhaps, but I will need to check.  Are you interested in every integer $n$, or primarily in the case $n=5$ (so that the curve is a Pfaffian quintic curve of arithmetic genus $1$)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am interested in the case $n=4$.

Comment: Yes, I meant to write $n = 4$ so that the curve is a Pfaffian quintic curve.  I wrote $n=5$ by mistake.

Comment: Could you, please, indicate a reference for Pfaffian varieties and how to use this presentation to have a nice presentation of the normal bundle?